# pywinauto Backend "uia" is not registered! problem

Tags: python, pywinauto

I am using pywinauto to control remote desktop.

```
"app = pywinauto.Application(backend="uia").start('mstsc')"
```

When I complier with original python 32-37,
it have error:

```
"File "../main.py", line 8, in <module>
app = pywinauto.Application(backend="uia").start('mstsc')
 File "..\pywinauto\application.py", line 905, in __init__
raise ValueError('Backend "{0}" is not registered!'.format(backend))
```

ValueError: Backend "uia" is not registered!"

When I complier with Anaconda, there is no Error

Answer (score 1):

It is typically happened when `comtypes` is not installed. Do `pip install comtypes==1.1.7` for your Python distribution and "uia" backend will be available. Maybe use full path to `pip.exe` to use correct pip. Like `<path-to-python>\Scripts\pip.exe`. `<path-to-python>` can be obtained this way in the interpreter: `import sys; print(sys.executable)`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to downgrade comtypes to 1.1.7:

```
pip uninstall comtypes
pip install comtypes=1.1.7
```

And I had to upgrade numpy:

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
```